# T-SQL: execute procedure obtaining parameter value from table (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that receives an ID parameter and performs insert/ updates.

I have about 25K records that need to be updated and I have been trying to figure out a way to enhance the single parameter stored procedure, so that it can process multiple values, or sets of Ids coming from a table.

The closest I gotten to do this, is by creating a cursor and looping through it whilst executing the stored procedure, unfortunately, I have come to realize that that is a very slow way of doing this.

I was wondering if I could get help modifying my stored procedure so that it can have a better performance.

Here is my code that uses a cursor.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Id    VARCHAR(32);

DECLARE csr CURSOR
FOR SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM table
    ORDER BY id;

OPEN csr;

FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO
    @Id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Running for '+@Id;
        EXEC update_product_xml_single_id @Id;
        FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO
            @Id;
    END;

CLOSE csr;
DEALLOCATE csr;
```

**UPDATE**

Following recommendation made by objectNotFound:

```
--Create User-defined Table Type
CREATE TYPE IdTableType AS TABLE ([Id] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

-- Modified old stored proc: update_product_xml_single_id, to receive the new type
CREATE PROCEDURE update_product_xml_tvp (@id IdTableType READONLY)

-- Called stored proc with a table variable
DECLARE @ID IdTableType

INSERT @ID 
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Products
WHERE ID LIKE 'N0%'
ORDER BY ID;

EXEC update_product_xml_tvp  @ID
```

The problem that I am facing is with the original stored procedure, or step #2. The only thing I modified was the name and the parameter type, but when I try to save the changes, I get errors like:

Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure update_product_xml_tvp, Line 43
Must declare the scalar variable "@id".

This scalar variable that the message is complaining about, is the same parameter that I just modified from varchar to table type. I am not sure how to proceed form here, or if I got the steps wrong. Any help is great, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is Table Valued Parameter as input to your stored procedure (update_product_xml_single_id).  So instead of passing a scalar value of type int (@Id) you will pass a list ( say @TVP ) that contains all the ID's that you are currently processing from the table "table" in your OP. And inside your stored procedure you can use that table variable @TVP just like any other ordinary table.

This Links shows you how to do it with an example (I have copied that example down below ):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Example from the above msdn link:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  

-- Step 1
/* Create a table type. */  
CREATE TYPE LocationTableType AS TABLE   
( LocationName VARCHAR(50)  
, CostRate INT );  
GO  

-- Step 2
/* Create a procedure to receive data for the table-valued parameter. */  
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo. usp_InsertProductionLocation  
    @TVP LocationTableType READONLY  
    AS   
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON  
    INSERT INTO AdventureWorks2012.Production.Location  
           (Name  
           ,CostRate  
           ,Availability  
           ,ModifiedDate)  
        SELECT *, 0, GETDATE()  
        FROM  @TVP;  
  END
  GO
```

**Usage Of passing the TVP  to the Stored Procedure:**

```
/* Declare a table variable that references the type. */  
DECLARE @LocationTVP AS LocationTableType;  -- This was created in Step 1 above.

/* Add data to the table variable. So this would be the same as your Declare Cursor SQL except its inserting into a Table Valued Parameter @LocationTVP */  
INSERT INTO @LocationTVP (LocationName, CostRate)  
    SELECT Name, 0.00  
    FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.StateProvince;  

/* Pass the table variable data in @LocationTVP to a stored procedure that now expects a Table valued parameter as input */  
EXEC usp_InsertProductionLocation @LocationTVP;  
GO
```

**EDIT:**

I just tested your CREATE SP Code and it works fine this is what I tried

```
CREATE TYPE IdTableType AS TABLE ([Id] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);
GO

-- Modified old stored proc: update_product_xml_single_id, to receive the new type
CREATE PROCEDURE update_product_xml_tvp 
( @id IdTableType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM  @id --- Obviously you will be using it differently but this is just to prove that it works
END
```

Also the "INTO" is missing in your insert statement

This:

```
INSERT @ID 
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Products
WHERE ID LIKE 'N0%'
ORDER BY ID;
```

Should be

```
INSERT INTO @ID 
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Products
WHERE ID LIKE 'N0%'
ORDER BY ID;
```

I added the INTO part to my code. But it is still giving me the same error.
I want to make sure that you know that the stored proc update_product_xml_tvp 
is the same stored procedure that I was using with the CURSOR, that the only thing I changed in it was the input parameter type. It used to be:
     @pf_id    VARCHAR(100)

and now it is: 
    @id id READONLY

Since I did not modified anything in the code in that procedure, the error comes from sections like:
    WHERE ai.ID = @id

Something does not look right, like @id is no longer the same data type as ai.id hence the comparison is no longer valid, but I do not know how to correct it, or where.

So to make sure this is right, I ended up with

```
 1. A user defined table type named id

 CREATE TYPE idTableType AS TABLE ([some_id] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

 2. A stored procedure that populates that table type:

 CREATE PROC [dbo].[mn_pass_id_table] ( @id_spVariable idTableType READONLY )
 AS
 BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON
     SELECT DISTINCT ID
     FROM Products
     WHERE ID LIKE 'N0%'
     ORDER BY ID;
 END

 3. And a modification to the stored procedure that existed already.

    From:
    ALTER PROCEDURE update_product_xml_single ( @id VARCHAR(100))

    To:       
    ALTER PROCEDURE update_product_xml_tvp (@id_spVariable idTableType READONLY)
```

Inside this procedure there are 4 WHERE conditions that I did not changed, nor modified, and that are giving me errors that won't let me update the stored procedure:

```
WHERE ai.ID  IN ( Select some_id from  @id_spVariable  )
```

My understanding is that in the end, I will be able to do the following from a new query window:

```
DECLARE @ID_Var_That_We_Will_Pass_To_Your_SP as idTableType 

INSERT INTO  @ID_Var_That_We_Will_Pass_To_Your_SP 
SELECT SOME_COLUMN FROM REAL_TABLE  ( This will be the one that you currently use to Declare the Cursor )

EXEC update_product_xml_tvp  @ID_Var_That_We_Will_Pass_To_Your_SP
```

I am sure I am messing something up here. I am really trying to get it right. Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: Thank you objectNotFound, it is a bit confusing how I am to implement the changes, in my code, but I will give that a try.

Comment: @erasmocarlos its pretty straight forward ... the last 3 statements in the example I copy/pasted are outside the SP. I will edit the post to clarify that.

Comment: the first section step 2, why does the insert gets data from a table named Location, and then on the last three statements in the insert statement, the tvp gets populated with data from a different table.

Comment: @erasmocarlos No, the insert gets data from @ TVP (Not Location) which is of Type LocationTableType. This @ TVP is a parameter to the SP and the way to PAss value into that @ TVP variable is shown in the  3 stmts listed under the usage section in my answer.  To avoid confusion think of LocationTableType as new custom datatype that is NOT available by default.(like a int, char, date, float etc ).

Comment: I am updating my original post with what I have done so far. Thank you.

Comment: @erasmocarlos ... Just responded ... see my edit in the answer above.

Comment: I edited your Edit in my answer to correct the issues. I used explicit names to make it easier to understand how the different objects relate and fit in this scenario. let me know.

Comment: After the last update that you made to the code, I was able to execute it without errors and for just a handul of records.I am now going to test against a larger table with 100K+ records.

Comment: Execution time got reduced from 30+ minutes, to only 4:30 minutes. This is for 126869 records. Awesome! If I could ask something before accepting this as the solution, in the last execution, where the table type parameter is passed to the sp, how can I add a PRINT so I can see what id is currently processed?

Comment: @erasmocarlos NO you cannot .. thats the Entire point of making it a "set based" solution.  This is the crux of set based programming that is the fundamental concept of SQL Programming. I cannot explain that in a post. I suggest you read some good articles on SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner but i think this will help you give it a try .

create user-defined function

<--step 1:-->

```
create type [dbo].[IdTableType ] as table 
(
[Id] BIGINT NOT NULL
)
GO
```

now <--step 2:-->

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_product_xml_tvp 
    (
    @table1 IdTableType  READONLY
    )
AS
BEGIN TRY
Declare  @ID BIGINT

 INSERT into YOUR_TABLE 
  (
   ID
   )
 SELECT DISTINCT ID
 FROM @table1
 WHERE ID LIKE 'N0%'
 ORDER BY ID;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
print error_message()
END CATCH
```

and call it through array

Comment: Hi abcool and thank you for your help. What confuses me is that update_product_xml_tvp, was a stored procedure already. That is the procedure that if you notice, I was using on my code with cursor, but the cursoer performance is too slow.

Comment: i had the same thing couple of months back where i need to insert multiple value to 2 table multiple time at single insertion. so , till now i am not having any slow or any error from it in fact i liked it. so what i suggest you is copy your code and create back up and delete the procedure and/(OR create new) table type and  procedure like up above and tell me from which platform you are using to call this procedure? so that i can provide hint if i can